# Should a comma be used before 'then' when it's the last word in a sentence?

Tags: punctuation

Should a comma be used before 'then' when it's the last word in a sentence?

*•Bob said, "If she goes, I'm not going, then."*

The example below appears to be incorrect.

*•Bob said, "If she goes, I'm not going then."*

Answer (score 1):

The comma marks a distinction between two different uses of *when*.

Without the comma, *then* is understood as a temporal adjunct: “I’m not going *at that time*”.

With the comma, *then* is understood as a postposed conjunction: “I’m not going *in consequence*”.

Answer (score 0):

I think both are doubtful from a grammatical viewpoint. Certainly they both lack clarity.

As StoneyB indicates there are two different meanings involved here. If I wanted to mean 'not at that time' I would say 'If she goes, I'm not going at the same time'.

If I wanted to mean 'in consequence', I would say 'If she goes, then I'm not going'.